# How to json unmarshalling with custom attribute type in Go

Tags: json, pointers, go, struct, unmarshalling

In my project, I've defined structures so that get data from JSON.
I tried to use `json.Unmarshal()` function. But it did not work for custom type attribute.

There was a structure like this:

```
type TestModel struct {
    ID   NullInt `json:"id"`
    Name string  `json:"name"`
}
```

In there, `NullInt` type was defined with implementations of `MarshalJSON()` and `UnmarshalJSON()` functions:

```
// NullInt ...
type NullInt struct {
    Int   int
    Valid bool
}

// MarshalJSON ...
func (ni NullInt) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !ni.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(ni.Int)
}

// UnmarshalJSON ...
func (ni NullInt) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    fmt.Println("UnmarshalJSON...")
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &ni.Int)
    ni.Valid = (err == nil)
    fmt.Println("NullInt:", ni)
    return err
}
```

In `main()` function, I implemented:

```
func main() {
    model := new(TestModel)
    JSON := `{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "model" 
    }`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(JSON), &model)
    fmt.Println("model.ID:", model.ID) 
}
```

In console, I got:

```
UnmarshalJSON...
NullInt: {1 true}
model.ID: {0 false}
```

As you can see, `NullInt.UnmarshalJSON()` was called and `ni` was what I expected but `model.ID`'s value. 
**What is the right way to implement `UnmarshalJSON()` function?**

To addition, when I set: `` JSON := `{"name": "model"}` `` (without `id`), console just was:

```
model.ID: {0 false}
```

That means, the `UnmarshalJSON()` function wasn't called then I didn't get `model.ID`'s value in right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UnmarshalJSON()` needs to modify the receiver, so you must use pointer receiver:

```
func (ni *NullInt) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // ...
}
```

The receiver and all parameters are just copies, and if you don't use a pointer, you may only modify a copy which will be discarded once the method returns. If you use a pointer receiver, that is also just a copy, but the pointed value will be the same, hence you may modify the original (pointed) object.

For consistency, also use pointer receiver for its other methods.

With this change it works and outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6yqwNT9jcTe)):

```
UnmarshalJSON...
NullInt: &{1 true}
model.ID: {1 true}
```