# What is correct way to declare UnmarshalJSON for custom type?

Tags: json, go

I create my own type as enum value in other languages (like java). I implement for deserialising UnmarshalJSON method for this type and see that marshal can't transform into custom type

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Mode string

const (
    UPDATE Mode = "update"
    INSERT Mode = "insert"
)
func (receiver Mode) String() string {
    switch receiver {
    case UPDATE:
        return string(UPDATE)
    case INSERT:
        return string(INSERT)
    default:
        return "UNRECOGNIZED"
    }
}
func (receiver Mode) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`"` + receiver.String() + `"`), nil
}
func (receiver Mode) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    receiver = Mode(data[1 : len(data)-1])
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var source Mode = "update"
    tmp, err := json.Marshal(source)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var received Mode

    err = json.Unmarshal(tmp, &received)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("source: ", source, "; received: ", received)
 }
```

And see output: `source:  update ; received:  UNRECOGNIZED`. How to write UnmarshalJSON for this type in correct way?

Comment: `Unmarshal()` has to modify the receiver, so it must be a pointer, see a working example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bkHFBMLZ4Nz).

Comment: The documentation contains an example: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example__customMarshalJSON . Rule of thumb: Always consult the whole documentation first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Unmarshal()` has to modify the receiver, so it must be a pointer, see this working example:

```
func (receiver *Mode) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    *receiver = Mode(data[1 : len(data)-1])
    return nil
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bkHFBMLZ4Nz)):

```
source:  update ; received:  update
```

See related question: [How to json unmarshalling with custom attribute type in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922229/how-to-json-unmarshalling-with-custom-attribute-type-in-go/57922284#57922284)

Also you should not handle generating / parsing the `string` yourself, there is no guarantee the input is valid JSON `string`, nor you don't handle proper escaping. Leave that to the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package.

So rather use this implementation:

```
func (receiver Mode) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(receiver.String())
}

func (receiver *Mode) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *receiver = Mode(s)
    return nil
}
```

This will handle invalid input and always generate valid JSON output. It outputs the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Mc4d9xDNdcD).